# OOP multiple inheritance, polymorphism, aggregation and enumeration

Tags: oop

Was asked the following question,

```
Class C inherits from class B, class B inherits from class A

Would you call this

(1) Multiple inheritance
(2) Polymorphism
(3) Aggregation
(4) Enumeration
```

Now I was unsure of this, so I said enumeration. Correct answer is polymorphism. I can sort of see why, but I am having trouble explaining this from OOP principles.

Also, when it comes to OOP, what would 3 and 4 indicate?

Thanks.

Comment: the correct answer is none of the above.  it's just 2 levels of inheritance.    it's not polymorphism : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Answer (score 0):

- **Aggregation** means, that an Object of class A contains (and makes use of) an object of class B.
- **Enumeration** denotes just a data type which can be given a finite (usually small) set of named values (to group "things" together).
- **Multiple Inheritance** would mean for a class to have more than one ancestor simultaneously (like Class a extends Class b, Class c, Class d).